# Adwhirl SDK always return 'Networkname - failure'; Adapter, calling handle, everything fine

Tags: android, networking, admob, adwhirl

Hey guys, 
sry, my third question belonging to this topic, but it doesnt start to work.

This is my result... each and every time. (all jars / adapter included) - also it results with '**Valid Adapter, calling handle**' but it also always say '**failure**'

```
11-22 13:14:02.634: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Will call rotateAd() in 30 seconds
11-22 13:14:32.634: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Rotating Ad
11-22 13:14:32.634: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Dart is <48.07955443549056> of <100.0>
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Showing ad:
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     nid: 7e779e360983412dad4d46c180a3493c
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     name: admob
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     type: 1
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     key: a14c9xxxx1e3aacf01
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     key2: 
11-22 13:14:32.644: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Valid adapter, calling handle()
11-22 13:14:32.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): AdMob failure
11-22 13:14:32.854: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(2621): nextRation is null!
11-22 13:14:32.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Will call rotateAd() in 30 seconds
11-22 13:15:02.854: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Rotating Ad
11-22 13:15:02.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Dart is <31.576009879080946> of <100.0>
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Showing ad:
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     nid: 7e779e360983412dad4d46c180a3493c
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     name: admob
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     type: 1
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     key: a14cxxxxxacf01
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     key2: 
11-22 13:15:02.864: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Valid adapter, calling handle()
11-22 13:15:03.114: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): AdMob failure
11-22 13:15:03.114: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(2621): nextRation is null!
11-22 13:15:03.114: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Will call rotateAd() in 30 seconds
11-22 13:15:33.117: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Rotating Ad
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Dart is <74.7807305713731> of <100.0>
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Showing ad:
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     nid: 90728xxxx734a2669b1c15ebbfd9
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     name: zestadz
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     type: 20
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     key: 14131C047A50414B4Exxxxxxx146584xxx56838229
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621):     key2: 
11-22 13:15:33.117: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Valid adapter, calling handle()
11-22 13:15:36.274: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): ZestADZ failure
11-22 13:15:36.274: ERROR/AdWhirl SDK(2621): nextRation is null!
11-22 13:15:36.274: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(2621): Will call rotateAd() in 30 seconds
```

my code, used to do so:

```
AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);
AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { "5B7D2A0178D212B6E94E22A15725A3D3" } ); //my mobile

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.widget54xx);
AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "548feca89xxadWhirlIDf482a");
adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);

final int DIP_WIDTH = 320; 
final int DIP_HEIGHT = 52; 
final float DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 
int scaledWidth = (int) (DENSITY * DIP_WIDTH + 0.5f); 
int scaledHeight = (int) (DENSITY * DIP_HEIGHT + 0.5f); 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams =
 new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
adWhirlLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //just for debug

layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
layout.invalidate();
```

the layout and everything seems to be fine. also height, should be working (results on my device with 52px) and i really dont know, whats the problem.

best regards,
and i'd be really thankful for any kind of tip,
cV /mike

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the result if no ads are available for your application. Due to the fact that every 'smallest App ' has ads, I really don't know why there aren't any ads available for my application (about 7000 users)

... dont know.

i changed to millenial ad network via adwhirl (use both) it always serves ads.. a pity that those arent as good as the admob ads.. but at least there are ads.

good luck, would also be very happy for an tips, regarding the admob ad fill rate.